# Ubuntu gets slower by the day

Tags: boot, 12.10, memory

Ive noticed that Ubuntu has been getting slower and slower to boot, launch programs, etc. I installed 12.04 about 4 months ago,now 12.10, running on a quad-core Q8300 Intel, 4GB Ram, and an 80GB WD IDE drive. For some reason (ever since 11.04), Ive noticed after installation, the speed is good. The longer I have the OS installed, every bootup gets slower and slower, launching programs get slower, frame rates change radically(onboard GF9400 gets anywhere from 60fps down to 12 in worst cases).

I would think maybe the HD is the issue, however I installed 11.10 on a 160GB SATA, and the same thing occurred.

Looking at system resources, I'm holding steady at 1GB memory usage (I have 4GB, but it's actually showing 3.6GB, dunno why), no swap usage, and using right around 4% on cpu currently. HD capacity is only 28% used.

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I love Ubuntu to death, but using other distros other than Ubuntu, I dont have this problem.

Comment: What applications do you normally have open?

Comment: To be more specific, when I say the OS is slow, i'm referring to the time from the on button being pressed to being able to open Firefox. Bootup time is right around 75 seconds (I have cifs connecting to a home server, which takes a little more time), as well as preload. After about 10 minutes or so, the lag clears up, but still seeing issues with fps performance; seems the longer the OS is on the Hard Drive, the slower the fps ends up being.

Comment: If performance, then either memory, IO, networking or computing power can be the bottleneck. I would first check the networking in your case: dynamic IP allocation, DNS resolution, ...

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things that can effect a computer slowdown that just doesn't seem to have a cause.

One is thermal problems, things like processors, Video cards, and memory overheating and causing the machine to throttle back.  Heat sink compound being old, not enough heat sink compound, and in some very rare cases too much heat sink compound, can be the problem.

Defective and/or dirty fans that cut in and out.

There are BIOS settings that can cause slow downs, memory timing issues, wait states, drive controller modes, etc.

Driver issues can cause slow down problems.

Power supply problems, even damaged connectors on the cables.

Bad filter caps.

Cards not seated properly in the motherboard.

You can even have AC power line problems like drop outs, low line voltage.

You could also be having network or internet connection problems, some are real simple things like old cables, blocked Antenna on WiFi, phone line noise on a DSL, or is it time of day related maybe your ISP is bogged down, etc.

Oh and here's a real off the wall one.  Do you have a case with a fan mounted on the side panel?  I saw one customer ware when the user pulled the system open and ran it with the side panel off, everything worked fine, put the side panel on and the computer gradually slowed down.  The power cable for the side fan was sticking in between the CPU fan fins with the side panel on and stopping the fan from starting and then the heat sink would heat up the CPU would throttle down.

And of course we have the old operator error.  Are you drinking too much coffee with lots of sugar and just thinking the machine is getting slow?  LOL!  OK, OK, probably not.

Anyway a few off the wall ideas that may help.